# Why is the first row of my pandas dataframe index the name of the index column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating an empty pandas dataframe as such:

```
self.tracker = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Portfolio Value', 'In Position','Capital',
                                       'Asset Quantity','Total Fees Paid'], 
                            index = ['Date'])
```

I want to insert new rows into the dataframe in a for-loop. Now I know that using `.concat()` is the most efficient way to do this. But all the examples are where it's an unrealisitc and rather pointless approach of using list comprehension with the `.concat()` method.

My index is that of a datetime object. The reason why I'm not creating a range of dates and setting that as the index, is that during the for loop, it's iterating through time series data with missing dates. I am inserting new rows into the dataframe via this way:

```
for (index1, row1), (index2, row2) in zip(self.ohlcv.iterrows(), self.features.iterrows()):
    self.tracker.loc[index1] = [self.asset_quantity * row1['Open'],
                                            self.in_position, self.capital,
                                            self.asset_quantity,
                                            self.cumulative_fees_paid]
```

Yet when I examine this dataframe, with `tracker.index` I get this as the result:

```
Index([             'Date', 2016-06-06 00:00:00, 2016-06-07 00:00:00,
       2016-06-08 00:00:00, 2016-06-09 00:00:00, 2016-06-10 00:00:00,
       2016-06-11 00:00:00, 2016-06-12 00:00:00, 2016-06-13 00:00:00,
       2016-06-14 00:00:00,
       ...
       2017-01-06 00:00:00, 2017-01-07 00:00:00, 2017-01-08 00:00:00,
       2017-01-09 00:00:00, 2017-01-10 00:00:00, 2017-01-11 00:00:00,
       2017-01-12 00:00:00, 2017-01-13 00:00:00, 2017-01-14 00:00:00,
       2020-04-05 00:00:00],
      dtype='object', length=225
```

So why is the first row of my index the name of the actual index column?

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your date column not an index when you initialise, and then once your loop is complete, set it as the index then? That way your data lines up :)

Answer (score 0):

Just initializing an empty dataframe based on your code

```
tracker = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Portfolio Value', 'In Position','Capital',
                                       'Asset Quantity','Total Fees Paid'], 
                            index = ['Date'])
```

When I query tracker in a python console it brings back;

```
Portfolio Value In Position Capital Asset Quantity  Total Fees Paid
Date        NaN         NaN           NaN      NaN              NaN
```

To fix this you need to specify that `Date` is the index name. Example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
```

```py
my_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

index = pd.date_range(my_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

tracker = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Portfolio Value', 'In Position','Capital',
                                           'Asset Quantity','Total Fees Paid'],
                                index = index)
tracker.index.name='Date'
```

- When you query your dataframe, i.e run `tracker` you get;

```
    Portfolio Value In Position Capital Asset Quantity  Total Fees Paid
    Date                    
    2020-07-02  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-03  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-04  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-05  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-06  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-07  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-08  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-09  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-10  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2020-07-11  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

- When you query your index, i.e `tracker.index` you get;

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05',
                   '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09',
                   '2020-07-10', '2020-07-11'],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq='D')
```